# How to make Outlook To-Do Bar always visible?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Sometimes when I start Outlook, the To-Do Bar is not visible.

[image]

I can enable it by selecting 'Normal' from the To-Do Bar drop-down menu.

[image]

After checking the 'Normal' option, the To-Do Bar is visible.

[image]

Even after doing this, the To-Do Bar usually hides itself again after I close Outlook again. When I open Outlook again, it's h

It doesn't always happen, but it happens enough that I wonder if there's some hidden switch that's flipped.

How do I do stop the To-Do Bar from hiding itself between Outlook sessions?